# Why isn't this code working to find the sum of multiples of 3 and 5 below the given number?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've started with some problems on HackerRank, and am stuck with one of the Project Euler problems available there.

The problem statement says: *Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N*

I've calculated the sum by finding *sum of multiple of 3 + sum of multiples of 5 - sum of multiples of 15* below the number `n`

```js
   function something(n) {
        n = n-1;
        let a = Math.trunc(n / 3);
        let b = Math.trunc(n / 5);
        let c = Math.trunc(n / 15);
        return (3 * a * (a + 1) + 5 * b * (b + 1) - 15 * c * (c + 1)) / 2;
    }
    console.log(something(1000)); //change 1000 to any number
```

With the values of `num` I've tried, it seems to work perfectly, but with two out of five test cases there, it returns a wrong answer (I can't access the test cases).

My question is what is the problem with my code? as the logic seems to be correct to me at least.

**Edit:** [Link to problem page](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/problem)

Comment: Logic seems fine for numbers. Maybe try check if `n` is number or something else.

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes `n` is a number. The only constraint for its value is `1 <= n <= 10^9`

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried with smaller numbers, and also with possibly border line cases like 3, 5, 15, 45 and 75. It gives correct answer with them. And the problem statement with constraints is visible to me there without a signup.

Comment: @Eagle If you notice on the problem description, It has three inputs and only two outputs. There is not output for number `2` may try returning `undefined` when `n` is less than `3`

Comment: @MaheerAli The code I am using there is working according to the input, and there is no issue with that because 3 of the 5 test cases yield the correct answer. Here, I have included only the code which calculates the sum, and not the one which gets the input(which is written there by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the numbers in the input are probably larger than what javascript can handle by default. As stated in the discussion on the hackkerrank-site, you will need an extra library (like: bignumber.js) for that.

The following info and code was posted by a user named *john_manuel_men1* on the discussion, where several other people had the same or similar problems like yours

> This is how I figured it out in javascript. BigNumber.js seems to store the results as strings. Using the .toNumber() method shifted the result for some reason, so I used .toString() instead.

```
function main() {
    var BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
    var t = new BigNumber(readLine()).toNumber();
    var n;
    for(var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        n = new BigNumber(readLine());
        answer();
    }
    function answer() {
    const a = n.minus(1).dividedBy(3).floor();
    const b = n.minus(1).dividedBy(5).floor();
    const c = n.minus(1).dividedBy(15).floor();
    const sumThree = a.times(3).times(a.plus(1)).dividedBy(2);
    const sumFive = b.times(5).times(b.plus(1)).dividedBy(2);
    const sumFifteen = c.times(15).times(c.plus(1)).dividedBy(2);
    const sumOfAll = sumThree.plus(sumFive).minus(sumFifteen);
    console.log(sumOfAll.toString());
    }
}
```